# BASH Script hangs after some processing on Ubuntu

Tags: bash, text-processing, background-process

I have been running below script on a Red Hat server, and it works fine and finishes the job. The file I am feeding it, contains half a million lines in it (approximately 500000 lines), and that's why (to finish it faster) I have added an '&' at the end of while loop block

But now I have setup a Desktop with 8 GB of RAM running Ubuntu 18.04 on it, and running the same code only finishes a few thousand lines and then hangs. I read a bit about it and increased the stack limit to unlimited as well and still it hung after 80000 lines or so, Any suggestions about how can I optimize the code or tune my PC parameters to always finish the job?

```
while read -r CID60
do    
 { 
       OLT=$(echo "$CID60" | cut -d"|" -f5) 
       ONID=${OLT}:$(echo "$CID60" | cut -d, -f2 | sed 's/ //g ; s/).*|//') 
       echo $ONID,$(echo "$CID60" | cut -d"|" -f3) >> $localpath/CID_$logfile.csv       
  } &     
done < $localpath/$CID7360
```

Input:

```
202-00_MSRFKH00OL6:R1.S1.LT7.PON8.ASSN45| Unlocked|12-654-0330|Up|202-00_MSRFKH00OL6|P282018767.C2028 ( network, R1.S1.LT7.PON8.ONT81.SERV1 )|

202-00_MSRFKH00OL6:R1.S1.LT7.PON8.ASSN46| Unlocked|12-654-0330|Down|202-00_MSRFKH00OL6|P282017856.C881 ( local, R1.S1.LT7.PON8.ONT81.C1.P1 )|

202-00_MSRFKH00OL6:R1.S1.LT7.PON8.ASSN52| Unlocked|12-664-1186|Up|202-00_MSRFKH00OL6|P282012623.C2028 ( network, R1.S1.LT7.PON8.ONT75.SERV1 )|
```

output:

```
202-00_MSRFKH00OL6:R1.S1.LT7.PON8.ONT81.SERV1,12-654-0330

202-00_MSRFKH00OL6:R1.S1.LT7.PON8.ONT81.C1.P1,12-654-0330

202-00_MSRFKH00OL6:R1.S1.LT7.PON8.ONT75.SERV1,12-664-1186
```

my output of interest is 5th column ( separated with pipe `|` ) being concatenated with part of last column, and then the third column

Comment: that's an awful lot of processes to fire off at, more or less, the same time. You might want to `wait` after some number of lines, or investigate other strategies to parallelize the job (such as GNU parallel)

Comment: @PerlDuck I have added the input and output of the script. of course it won't run as it is since some of the variables are defined out of this code. Also I am thinking to try sed or awk to do this job, it might be a lot quicker but I need to learn how to write such expression....

Comment: @glennjackman I have been reading about parallel, can you suggest some way how I can use it in a loop like this one above?

Comment: Your code seems amenable to a single `sed` instruction operating on the input file  that would run thousands of times faster. `awk` would also be a solution.

Comment: @xenoid can you please suggest some sed expression?

Comment: So what was the problem? Lack of resources? Disk bottleneck? "Just rewrite your script" isn't necessarily a repeatable solution. Also, fwiw, this should be on SO.

Comment: @pbhj lack of knowledge I would say, I was just bombarding the PC with millions of jobs, which was done with better ways using perl/awk/python/parallel. I thought the problem was Ubuntu related as the same script was previously working on RedHat server,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Perl solution

This script doesn't do anything in parallel but is quite fast regardless.
Save it as `filter.pl` (or whatever name you prefer) and make it executable.

```perl
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

while( <> ) {
    if ( /^(?:[^|]+\|){2}([^|]+)\|[^|]+\|([^|]+)\|[^,]+,\s*(\S+)/ ) {
        print "$2:$3,$1\n";
    }
}
```

I copied your sample data until I got 1,572,864 lines and then ran it as follows:

```
me@ubuntu:~> time ./filter.pl < input.txt > output.txt
real    0m3,603s
user    0m3,487s
sys     0m0,100s

me@ubuntu:~> tail -3 output.txt
202-00_MSRFKH00OL6:R1.S1.LT7.PON8.ONT81.SERV1,12-654-0330
202-00_MSRFKH00OL6:R1.S1.LT7.PON8.ONT81.C1.P1,12-654-0330
202-00_MSRFKH00OL6:R1.S1.LT7.PON8.ONT75.SERV1,12-664-1186
```

If you prefer one-liners, do:

```
perl -lne 'print "$2:$3,$1" if /^(?:[^|]+\|){2}([^|]+)\|[^|]+\|([^|]+)\|[^,]+,\s*(\S+)/;' < input.txt > output.txt
```

Comment: Indeed this perl solution has been fastest, took about less than a second to process 300K lines, I am preparing some other lookups like scripts, I will be looking forward to further help, thanks everyone, all were helpful, but @perlduck's solution was fastest, and as my original while loop wasn't producing results in order, so the order won't matter for me anyway

Comment: @Ibraheem, Yes this `perl` solution is very good, probably with a great margin fast enough for your purpose. -- But try my **`tr` and `cut`** solution, which is actually faster in my computer (and I think easier to understand and modify), and wait for a solution with **`parallel` and `perl`** by PerlDuck, which I think can be the fastest of them all.

Comment: @sudodus I tried your solution, it was really fast (took about 0.205 seconds), but the columns are not coming as I want them and it has a pipe in the middle,

Comment: @Ibraheem, Is it important to have the format that you want (order of columns and separators between the column)? The reason why my solution is fast is that it does as little as possible, still showing what you need (but in a different order). If you prefer another separator, it is possible, space `' '` would cost no extra time, another separator would cost some extra time for a `tr` or `tr -s` command, but not very much.

Comment: separator and order of the columns is important to keep according to my intended output,

Comment: I finally made a oneliner with `awk`, which is on par with the `perl` oneliner (slightly faster in my computer), maybe easier to understand and edit, if you would need that in the future. The outputs of these two oneliners are exactly the same for the test case. See the end of my answer. Any of the two solutions should be good for you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89134/discussion-between-ibraheem-and-sudodus).

Answer (score 5):

A pure sed solution:

```
sed -r 's/^[^|]+\|[^|]+\|([^|]+)\|[^|]+\|([^|]+)\|.+\( .+, ([^ ]+).+/\2:\3,\1/' <in.dat >out.dat
```

Comment: +1: Nice with a pure sed solution :-) But my `cut` and `sed` solution is faster ;-)

Comment: Yes I know. But mine produces the result in the requested order 

Comment: That's right, we will see how important it is to get exactly what the OP prescribes. By the way, I think you drop one character, `MSRFKH00OL6` --> `MSRFKH00OL` in your output. I think you can fix that with a minor edit.

Comment: @sudodus Yes, transcription error. Fixed :)

Comment: I timed your new one-liner and it works well, actually slightly faster than before. I don't know if there was something else happening in my computer, anyway, I edited my answer to show the new result :-)

Answer (score 5):

```
doit() {
  # Hattip to @sudodus
  tr ' ' '|' |
    tr -s '|' '|' |
    cut -d '|' -f 3,5,9 
}
export -f doit
parallel -k --pipepart --block -1 -a input.txt doit > output.txt
```

- `-k` keep the order, so the first/last line of the input will also be the first/last line of the output
- `--pipepart` splits the file on the fly
- `--block -1` into 1 chunk per CPU thread
- `-a input.txt` the file to split
- `doit` the command (or bash function) to call

Speedwise the `parallel` (yellow) version outperforms the `tr` (black) around 200 MB on my system (Seconds vs MB):

[image: graph]

Comment: Great! Worth mentioning that this only works with GNU Parallel (`sudo apt install parallel`) and not the _parallel_ command that is installed by default. The latter has fewer options.

Comment: I'd love to try this also, the version without parallel finished the job in 0.2 seconds, but didn't keep order of columns according to desired output,

Comment: @ole Tange I have tried your `parallel` version as well, and it gave similar output as the @sudodus version, but only parallel took a few more clock ticks while original `tr` and `cut` version was way faster

Comment: I have slightly modified the solution from sudodus and used `awk` instead of `cut` and re-arranged columns to my required format, and it works fine as well, and took the same processing time with parallel as well. This is what I replaced the `cut` command with `awk -F "|" '{ print $5 ":" $9 "," $3}' `

Comment: +1; Thanks for showing how to do it with parallel :-)

Comment: Pretty cool diagram. And, btw., nice to have a `parallel` solution from the very author of this awesome tool. :-) Just for my understanding: X axis is filesize, Y axis is processing time, Yellow is `parallel`, Black is `tr`? /// I tried my Perl solution with and without `parallel` and came to the conclusion that in this particular case there is only little improvement with `parallel`. I think the actual files are just to small and `parallel` cannot compensate the overhead needed for its processing _in this case_.

Comment: loving all the support from all of you experts, as this was probably my first question on the forum, not sure if there is a place to write testimonial or say thanks personally so I have to use this comment for the purpose. I realize that I have so many other tasks which really need to be optimized, I have been doing it the wrong way (the way I knew so far) for a long time,

Answer (score 3):

## Oneliners by me and other persons as well as some scripts tested

If the order of the items and the separators can be different from what you specify in the question, I thought the following one-liner would do it,

```
< input tr ' ' '|' | cut -d '|' -f 4,6,10 > output
```

but in a comment you wrote that you need exactly the specified format.

I added a solution with **'awk'**, which is approximately on par with PerlDuck's solution with `perl`. See the end of this answer.

```
< input awk '{gsub("\\|"," "); print $5 ":" $9 "," $3}' > output
```

## Test of oneliners and small scripts

The test was done in my computer with Lubuntu 18.04.1 LTS, 2*2 processors and 4 GiB RAM.

I made a huge `infile` by 'doubling 20 times' from your demo `input` (1572864 lines), so some margin to your 500000 lines,

**Oneliner with `cut` and `sed`**:

```
$ < infile cut -d '|' -f 3,5,6 | sed -e 's/|[A-Z].*, /|/' -e 's/ )$//' > outfile
$ wc -l infile
1572864 infile
$ wc -l outfile
1572864 outfile
$ tail outfile
12-664-1186|202-00_MSRFKH00OL6|R1.S1.LT7.PON8.ONT75.SERV1
12-654-0330|202-00_MSRFKH00OL6|R1.S1.LT7.PON8.ONT81.SERV1
12-654-0330|202-00_MSRFKH00OL6|R1.S1.LT7.PON8.ONT81.C1.P1
12-664-1186|202-00_MSRFKH00OL6|R1.S1.LT7.PON8.ONT75.SERV1
12-654-0330|202-00_MSRFKH00OL6|R1.S1.LT7.PON8.ONT81.SERV1
12-654-0330|202-00_MSRFKH00OL6|R1.S1.LT7.PON8.ONT81.C1.P1
12-664-1186|202-00_MSRFKH00OL6|R1.S1.LT7.PON8.ONT75.SERV1
12-654-0330|202-00_MSRFKH00OL6|R1.S1.LT7.PON8.ONT81.SERV1
12-654-0330|202-00_MSRFKH00OL6|R1.S1.LT7.PON8.ONT81.C1.P1
12-664-1186|202-00_MSRFKH00OL6|R1.S1.LT7.PON8.ONT75.SERV1
```

#### Timing

We might expect, that a pure `sed` solution would be faster, but I think that reordering of the data slows it down, so that the `cut` and `sed` solution is faster. Both solutions work without any problem in my computer.

**Oneliner with `cut` and `sed`:**

```
$ time < infile cut -d '|' -f 3,5,6 | sed -e 's/|[A-Z].*, /|/' -e 's/ )$//' > outfile

real    0m8,132s
user    0m8,633s
sys     0m0,617s
```

**A pure `sed` oneliner by xenoid:**

```
$ time sed -r 's/^[^|]+\|[^|]+\|([^|]+)\|[^|]+\|([^|]+)\|.+\( .+, ([^ ]+).+/\2:\3,\1/' <infile > outfile-sed 

real    1m8,686s
user    1m8,259s
sys     0m0,344s
```

**A `python` script using a regex with non-greedy matches by xeniod:**

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys,re

pattern=re.compile(r'^[^|]+?\|[^|]+?\|([^|]+?)\|[^|]+?\|([^|]+?)\|[^,]+?, (.+) \)\|$')

for line in sys.stdin:
    match=pattern.match(line)
        if match:
            print(match.group(2)+':'+match.group(3)+','+match.group(1))

$ time < infile ./python-ng > outfile.pyng

real    0m8,055s
user    0m7,359s
sys 0m0,300s

$ python --version
Python 2.7.15rc1
```

**A `perl` oneliner by PerlDuck is faster than the previous oneliners:**

```
$ time perl -lne 'print "$2:$3,$1" if /^(?:[^|]+\|){2}([^|]+)\|[^|]+\|([^|]+)\|[^,]+,\s*(\S+)/;' < infile > outfile.perl

real    0m5,929s
user    0m5,339s
sys     0m0,256s
```

**Oneliner with `tr` and `cut` with a `tr -s` command:**

I used `tr` to convert the spaces in the input file to pipeline characters and then `cut` could do it all without `sed`. As you can see, `tr` is much faster than `sed`. The `tr -s` command removes double pipes in the input, which is a good idea, particularly if there can be repeated spaces or pipes in the input file. It does not cost much.

```
$ time < infile tr ' ' '|' | tr -s '|' '|' | cut -d '|' -f 3,5,9 > outfile-tr-cut

real    0m1,277s
user    0m1,781s
sys     0m0,925s
```

**Oneliner with `tr` and `cut` without the `tr -s` command, fastest so far:**

```
time < infile tr ' ' '|' | cut -d '|' -f 4,6,10 > outfile-tr-cut

real    0m1,199s
user    0m1,020s
sys     0m0,618s


$ tail outfile-tr-cut
12-664-1186|202-00_MSRFKH00OL6|R1.S1.LT7.PON8.ONT75.SERV1
12-654-0330|202-00_MSRFKH00OL6|R1.S1.LT7.PON8.ONT81.SERV1
12-654-0330|202-00_MSRFKH00OL6|R1.S1.LT7.PON8.ONT81.C1.P1
12-664-1186|202-00_MSRFKH00OL6|R1.S1.LT7.PON8.ONT75.SERV1
12-654-0330|202-00_MSRFKH00OL6|R1.S1.LT7.PON8.ONT81.SERV1
12-654-0330|202-00_MSRFKH00OL6|R1.S1.LT7.PON8.ONT81.C1.P1
12-664-1186|202-00_MSRFKH00OL6|R1.S1.LT7.PON8.ONT75.SERV1
12-654-0330|202-00_MSRFKH00OL6|R1.S1.LT7.PON8.ONT81.SERV1
12-654-0330|202-00_MSRFKH00OL6|R1.S1.LT7.PON8.ONT81.C1.P1
12-664-1186|202-00_MSRFKH00OL6|R1.S1.LT7.PON8.ONT75.SERV1
```

**Oneliner with `awk`, fast but not the fastest,**

```
< input awk '{gsub("\\|"," "); print $5 ":" $9 "," $3}' > output

$ time < infile awk '{gsub("\\|"," "); print $5 ":" $9 "," $3}' > outfile.awk

real    0m5,091s
user    0m4,724s
sys     0m0,365s
```

**`awk` with `parallel` implemented according to Ole Tange reduces the real time from 5s to 2s:**

```
#!/bin/bash

doit() {
 awk '{gsub("\\|"," "); print $5 ":" $9 "," $3}'
}
export -f doit
parallel -k --pipepart --block -1 -a infile doit > outfile.parallel-awk

$ time ./parallel-awk 
# Academic tradition requires you to cite works you base your article on.
# When using programs that use GNU Parallel to process data for publication
#please cite:

#  O. Tange (2011): GNU Parallel - The Command-Line Power Tool,
#  ;login: The USENIX Magazine, February 2011:42-47.

# This helps funding further development; AND IT WON'T COST YOU A CENT.
#If you pay 10000 EUR you should feel free to use GNU Parallel without citing.

# To silence this citation notice: run 'parallel --citation'.

real    0m1,994s
user    0m5,015s
sys     0m0,984s
```

We can expect that the advantage with `parallel` will increase with bigger size of the input file as described by the diagram in Ola Tange's answer to this question.

**Speed summary:** the 'real' time according to  `time` rounded to 1 decimal

```
1m 8.7s - sed
   8.1s - cut & sed
   7.4s - python
   5.9s - perl
   5.1s - awk
   2.0s - parallel & awk
   1.2s - tr & cut
```

Finally, I note that the oneliners with `sed`, `python`, `perl`, `awk` and {`parallel` & `awk`} create an output file with the prescribed format.

```
$ tail outfile.awk
202-00_MSRFKH00OL6:R1.S1.LT7.PON8.ONT75.SERV1,12-664-1186
202-00_MSRFKH00OL6:R1.S1.LT7.PON8.ONT81.SERV1,12-654-0330
202-00_MSRFKH00OL6:R1.S1.LT7.PON8.ONT81.C1.P1,12-654-0330
202-00_MSRFKH00OL6:R1.S1.LT7.PON8.ONT75.SERV1,12-664-1186
202-00_MSRFKH00OL6:R1.S1.LT7.PON8.ONT81.SERV1,12-654-0330
202-00_MSRFKH00OL6:R1.S1.LT7.PON8.ONT81.C1.P1,12-654-0330
202-00_MSRFKH00OL6:R1.S1.LT7.PON8.ONT75.SERV1,12-664-1186
202-00_MSRFKH00OL6:R1.S1.LT7.PON8.ONT81.SERV1,12-654-0330
202-00_MSRFKH00OL6:R1.S1.LT7.PON8.ONT81.C1.P1,12-654-0330
202-00_MSRFKH00OL6:R1.S1.LT7.PON8.ONT75.SERV1,12-664-1186
```

Comment: Nice :-) Try `perl -lne 'print "$2:$3,$1" if /^(?:[^|]+\|){2}([^|]+)\|[^|]+\|([^|]+)\|[^,]+,\s*(\S+)/;' < input.txt > output.txt`. I also repeated the input until I got 1,572,864 lines and it runs in ~3,5 seconds on my machine.

Comment: Note that the desired output is not `|` separated but uses `:` and `,`.

Comment: @PerlDuck, 1. Yes, I will time your perl expression :-) 2. I know (and wrote about it in the beginning of my answer), that it is not exactly what the OP wants, but similar enough to be useful, and, I think, faster than if rearranged to the exact specification.

Comment: Sorry, I missed your introductory sentence about the different separators. Btw., [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29033016/5830574) is an interesting approach using GNU parallel ;-)

Comment: @PerlDuck, If you make an answer with your fast `perl` oneliner, I will upvote it :-)

Comment: Done. Maybe I'll play a bit with GNU parallel this evening and post an improvement...

Comment: @PerlDuck, I'm looking forward to the result with GNU parallel :-)

Comment: OK I lose the race, but I'm still vastly faster that the OP's solution :)

Comment: @xenoid, That's right, the original solution that reads lines in a shell and performs various operations on each line will be very slow, while your solution is a clean `sed` oneliner and therefore much more efficient.

Comment: @PerlDuck I'll be looking forward to further enhancements or if anyone can post a Python version, that will be great!

Comment: @PerlDuck am sorry if this is inappropriate, as I am almost new to these forums, but could you help me with this question as well? https://askubuntu.com/q/1114803/801943

Answer (score 2):

### Python

```
import sys,re

pattern=re.compile(r'^.+\|.+\|(.+)\|.+\|(.+)\|.+, (.+) \)\|$')

for line in sys.stdin:
match=pattern.match(line)
if match:
    print(match.group(2)+':'+match.group(3)+','+match.group(1))
```

(works with both Python2 and Python3)

Using a regex with non-greedy matches is 4x faster (avoids backtracking?) and puts python on par with the cut/sed method (python2 being a bit faster than python3)

```
import sys,re

pattern=re.compile(r'^[^|]+?\|[^|]+?\|([^|]+?)\|[^|]+?\|([^|]+?)\|[^,]+?, (.+) \)\|$')

for line in sys.stdin:
match=pattern.match(line)
if match:
    print(match.group(2)+':'+match.group(3)+','+match.group(1))
```

Comment: This one also works fine as expected but a bit slower then the perl one,