# need to enhance script for lookups from multiple csv files

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, text-processing, background-process

I need to enhance my below script which takes an input file that contains unique lines (almost a million lines). Against each line, it has different values in 3 lookup files which I intend to add in my output as comma separated values. below script works fine but it takes hours to finish the job, I am looking for some real fast solution which would also be less heavy on the system

```
#!/bin/bash
while read -r ONT
do
{

ONSTATUS=$(grep "$ONT," lookupfile1.csv | cut -d" " -f2)
CID=$(grep "$ONT." lookupfile3.csv | head -1 | cut -d, -f2)
line1=$(grep "$ONT.C2.P1," lookupfile2.csv | head -1 | cut -d"," -f2,7 | sed 's/ //')
line2=$(grep "$ONT.C2.P2," lookupfile2.csv | head -1 | cut -d"," -f2,7 | sed 's/ //')
echo "$ONT,$ONSTATUS,$CID,$line1,$line2" >> BUwithPO.csv
} & 
done < inputfile.csv
```

inputfile.csv contains lines like below:

```
343OL5:LT1.PN1.ONT1
343OL5:LT1.PN1.ONT10
225OL0:LT1.PN1.ONT34
225OL0:LT1.PN1.ONT39
343OL5:LT1.PN1.ONT100
225OL0:LT1.PN1.ONT57
```

lookupfile1.csv contains:

```
343OL5:LT1.PN1.ONT100, Down,Locked,No
225OL0:LT1.PN1.ONT57, Up,Unlocked,Yes
343OL5:LT1.PN1.ONT1, Down,Unlocked,No
225OL0:LT1.PN1.ONT34, Up,Unlocked,Yes
225OL0:LT1.PN1.ONT39, Up,Unlocked,Yes
```

lookupfile2.csv contains:

```
225OL0:LT1.PN1.ONT34.C2.P1, +123125302766,REG,DigitMap,Unlocked,_media_BNT,FD_BSFU.xml,
225OL0:LT1.PN1.ONT57.C2.P1, +123125334019,REG,DigitMap,Unlocked,_media_BNT,FD_BSFU.xml,
225OL0:LT1.PN1.ONT57.C2.P2, +123125334819,REG,DigitMap,Unlocked,_media_BNT,FD_BSFU.xml,
343OL5:LT1.PN1.ONT100.C2.P11, +123128994019,REG,DigitMap,Unlocked,_media_ANT,FD_BSFU.xml,
```

lookupfile3.csv contains:

```
343OL5:LT1.PON1.ONT100.SERV1,12-654-0330
343OL5:LT1.PON1.ONT100.C1.P1,12-654-0330
343OL5:LT7.PON8.ONT75.SERV1,12-664-1186
225OL0:LT1.PN1.ONT34.C1.P1.FLOW1,12-530-2766
225OL0:LT1.PN1.ONT57.C1.P1.FLOW1,12-533-4019
```

output is:

```
225OL0:LT1.PN1.ONT57, Up,Unlocked,Yes,12-533-4019,+123125334019,FD_BSFU.xml,+123125334819,FD_BSFU.xml
225OL0:LT1.PN1.ONT34, Up,Unlocked,Yes,12-530-2766,+123125302766,FD_BSFU.xml,
343OL5:LT1.PN1.ONT1, Down,Unlocked,No,,,
343OL5:LT1.PN1.ONT100, Down,Locked,No,,,
343OL5:LT1.PN1.ONT10,,,,
225OL0:LT1.PN1.ONT39, Up,Unlocked,Yes,,,
```

Comment: When I run your demo example in Lubuntu 18.04.1 LTS, I get a different output, not what you show as output, but something quite different. Please check that your files are matching.

Comment: @sudodus can you share the output you got? I ran again and I got the same output except for one line: `Down,Unlocked,No,,,` which I deleted from the output, and I need to look into it, but the output I shared in my question is the intended output

Comment: So the bit to the first comma is the key, then you want to catenate the other files' entries using that key? Is perl/python available? This question is not Ubuntu, it should be on StackOverflow or Unix.se.com

Comment: Looks like you are re-implementing a relational database with CSV files. Can't you put the data in a DB?

Comment: If the lookup files aren't gigantic, they can be transformed into Python dictionaries.

Comment: @pbhj yeh, perl, python is available, and yes the value up to first comma can be taken as key for looking up

Comment: @PerlDuck these are some files generated on daily basis with and I want to get values of interest from each different file and put them together in a single file, I studied databases and programming a very long time ago but it is not my primary field so looking out for help for now

Comment: @xenoid can you please suggest a solution using python dictionaries as you mentioned?

Comment: No, because the more I look into your problem, the more I think it is best handled with a database.

Comment: How large (number of lines) are those lookupfiles?

Comment: There is a good solution with `awk` at [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54489094/7347387) :-)

Comment: @PerlDuck these files contain about 200000 lines each

Comment: @sudodus Now there's also a [Perl solution over on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54496917/5830574). I didn't optimize it (due to lack of sample data) but would guess it is slower than the `awk` scripts. /// I'm not sure how to handle this question. Usually we don't appreciate cross-posts and to be honest, this question is not exactly related to Ubuntu.

Comment: @PerlDuck, I agree.SO is the right place for the answers in this case. (I am not registered there.)

Comment: @sudodus btw, when you run the script from the question and get a different order of output lines, then this stems from the fact that each line is processed _in background_ and the output is not properly serialized. The order of lines in the output is more or less random.